# WooCommerce: Shipping by Weight and cost

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to get a shipping price per kilo from 1 kilo to 10 prices, and from 11 kilos to 20 prices, but if the amount is above $100, the shipping will be free and I don’t have to calculate the price of the kilo, I try to add that when the total purchase is $100  The shipping account is cancelled, but I could not, can you help, thank you?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'binary_carpenter_weight_based_shipping_tiers', 10, 16 );
   
function binary_carpenter_weight_based_shipping_tiers( $rates, $package ) {
     

    if ( WC()->cart->cart_contents_weight <= 10 ) {
      
    foreach($rates as $key => $value)
    {
      if ($value->cost != 4.49  && $value->method_id != 'local_pickup')
        unset($rates[$key]);
        
    }
       
       } elseif ( WC()->cart->cart_contents_weight <= 16 ) {
       
    foreach($rates as $key => $value)
    {
      if ($value->cost != 10  && $value->method_id != 'local_pickup')
        unset($rates[$key]);
        
    }
       
    }  if ($value->cost != 100  && $value->method_id != 'local_pickup'){
    
    unset($rates['flat_rate:12']);
    unset($rates['flat_rate:15']);

     }

  return $rates;    
    
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this? 

If CART CONTENT WEIGHT less than 10 KG = ONE SHIPPING COST 
If CART CONTENT WEIGHT less than 20 KG and greater than 10 KG = ANOTHER SHIPPING COST 

If the TOTAL COST OF CART is more than or equal to 100$ = FREE SHIPPING.

Comment: Right! for 100$/200$ is free.

Answer (score 0):

Well, In that case, you have written your condition this way, I commented on my code for you to understand better. You can get your cart weight from the $package parameter. The code is tested and works at my end.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'binary_carpenter_weight_based_shipping_tiers', 9999, 2 );
function binary_carpenter_weight_based_shipping_tiers( $rates, $package ) {

    $total_weight = 0; // Initial variable

    // Get cart items for the current shipping package (to calculate package weight)
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        $total_weight += floatval( $item['data']->get_weight() ) * $item['quantity'];
    }

    if($total_weight <= 10){
        $extra_cost = 30; //YOUR COST IF CART CONTENT WEIGHT less than 10 KG
    }elseif ($total_weight <= 20){
        $extra_cost = 50; //YOUR COST IF CART CONTENT WEIGHT less than 20 KG and greater than 10 KG
    }else{
        $extra_cost = 0;
    }

    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        if( 'free_shipping' !== $rate->method_id ){
            $has_taxes = false; // Initializing
            $taxes     = array(); // Initializing

            $initial_cost = $rate->cost;
            $new_cost     = $initial_cost + $extra_cost;

            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $new_cost; // Set new rate cost

            // Loop through taxes array (change taxes rate cost if enabled)
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $tax > 0 ){
                    // Get the tax rate conversion
                    $tax_rate    = $tax / $initial_cost;

                    // Set the new tax cost in the array
                    $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate;
                    $has_taxes   = true; // Enabling tax changes
                }
            }
            // set array of shipping tax cost
            if( $has_taxes ) {
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;

}
```

Code goes to your active child theme/theme functions.php. Make sure after add it to functions.php you have cleared you cart and try to test again. In some cases you might need to clear customer sessions from **WooCommerce > Status > Tools**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much "Abdullah Al Faruk
"